# Как найти маленький объект? autoit

Tags: autoit

Есть приложение, в котором появляется маленький объект на случайных координатах в окне приложения. Как его можно найти? При условии, что и поиск по картинке (в формате bmp), и поиск по пикселям не подходят, так как при каждой смене координат объекта программа уже не может его найти. Объект всегда имеет одинаковый цвет и форму.

Comment: "при каждой смене позиции объекта **программа не видит цвета\картинки, сделанной ранее**" - расшифруйте пожалуйста.

Comment: добавьте все эти уточнения в вопрос, а комментарий после можете удалить

Comment: Тебе нужно делать скрин и по нему искать обект. Я такое на с++ делал.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка А в чем разница между поиском на экране и поиском на скриншоте? Это же, как я понимаю, мою проблему никак не решает.

Comment: Как это я так понимаю что при попиксыльном поиске пока вы пройдётесь по пиксэлям то объект убегает? Если мы делаем скришнот то мы замораживаемым кадр и спокойно не спеша ищем объект. Возможно я не понял вопрос.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка Объект статичен и после каждой перезагрузки приложения он меняет свои координаты и программа его не видит, хотя цвет и форма идентична (по крайней мере на глаз). При этом, если взять цвет того же пикселя, то он чуть-чуть отличается. Пример - на одной координате самый яркий пиксель на объекте это 0xC3C253, а на другой - 0xC3C351. НО! Если сделать скриншоты и посмотреть через фотошоп цвета самого яркого пикселя - они не отличаются. Использую AutoIt последнее версии.

Comment: Так при проверке пик селя сделайте условия, чтобы он не просто проверял равно не равно, а в диапазоне от и до, разрешите отклонение проще делать такую проверку, если пик сель преобразовать в черно белый но не обизатильно. Также вы можете розщитать свет целой области и искать по нему.

Comment: Берете область по размеру вашего образца bmp например 15х15 и розщитываете средние значение цвета, у вас получается один цвет, находите на экране такие же кубики, и сравниваете их с эталоном, выбираете наиболее близкий () его позицию.  При поиске на экране сдвиг должен бить не 15 пикселей а 1.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка Не факт, что у меня получится подобное реализовать сразу и правильно, но это определенно возможное решение. Спасибо!